# how to find out value of <a> tag using jquery in php

Tags: php, jquery

i have `<a id="skin_title1"><?php echo $skin;?> </a>`

i want the value of `<?php echo $skin;?>` in jquery.
i have tried this `$j('#skin_title'+$studio_id).val()` but i dont get value.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you need:

```
<script>
    alert($('#skin_title1').html()); //here will alert you value
</script>
```

**OR**

```
$("#skin_title1").get().innerHTML
```

**OR**

```
$("#skin_title1").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery html:

```
$("#skin_title1").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$("#skin_title1").text() 
$("#skin_title1").html()
```